# Using a regular expression with zip command for directory exclusions

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression, zip

I am trying to zip up my application and would like to exclude all of my image directories apart from one.

Consider the following folder structure:

```
/images
│
└───/foo // exclude
│
└───/bar // exclude
│
└───/foobar // exclude
│
└───/icons // include
```

From what I understand, the `zip` command does not allow the use of regular expressions within it's arguments and as such, I am not sure what to do.

I have done some research and believe there is a way to use `ls`/`find` but I am not entirely sure how. Can anyone suggest how I can go about this?

This is my current command (excludes **all** image directories):

```
zip -rq application.zip . -x vendor/\* node_modules/\* .git/\* .env public/assets/images/\*
```

and I believe I need something like this (I haven't got the regex to actually work):

```
find ./public/assets/images -maxdepth 1 -regex '\.\/(?!icons).* | zip -rq application.zip . -x vendor/\* node_modules/\* .git/\* .env INSERT_FIND_RESULTS_HERE
```

### Update

The full application directory looks similar to the following:

```
/www
│   .env
│   .env.example
│   .env.pipelines
│   .gitignore
│   artisan
│   etc...
│
└───/.ebextensions
└───/.git
└───/app
└───/bootstrap
└───/config
└───/database
└───/infrastructure
└───/node_modules
└───/public
│   │   .htaccess
│   │   index.php
│   │   etc...
│   │
│   └───/assets
│   │   └───/fonts
│   │   └───/images
│   │   │   └───/blog
│   │   │   └───/brand
│   │   │   └───/capabilities
│   │   │   └───/common
│   │   │   └───/contact
│   │   │   └───/icons
│   │   │   └───/misc
│   │   │   └───etc...
│   │
│   └───/js
│   └───/css
│   
└───/storage
└───/tests
└───/vendor
```

I want to zip all of the files excluding:

```
vendor/
node_modules/
.git/
.env
public/assets/images/ (excluding public/assets/images/icons)
```

### Update 2

Since posting, I have learned that `find` does not allow lookaheads in it's regular expressions and therefore I need to use a combination of `grep` and find. As such, this is my latest command (still not working though):

```
find ./public/assets/images -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./public/assets/images/.*' | grep -oP '\./public/assets/images/(?!icons).*' | xargs zip -rq application.zip . -x vendor/\* node_modules/\* .git/\* .env
```

Note, I don't know how to use `xargs` and I believe this is why the above does not work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create the archive in two steps:

1. Create the archive, excluding everything you want to exclude:

   ```
   zip -r application.zip . -x 'vendor/*' 'node_modules/*' '.git/*' .env 'public/assets/images/*'
   ```
2. Add to that same archive the one folder that you want to include from the excluded directory:

   ```
   zip -r application.zip public/assets/images/icons/
   ```

(the default behavior of `zip` is to add files to an existing archive, if it already exists)

Comment: I had no idea that you could add items to an existing archive. This is actually a great solution as it prevents the need for some very long unreadable command

Comment: Also agree with @BenCarey commentary. Also didn't know that it was possible to add items to an existing archive.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @BenCarey If you wish to modify the accepted answer, I am ok with that.

Comment: @PauloTomé - that's very kind of you, I didn't want to without you saying as I know you put a lot of time into your efforts and I very much appreciated that!

Comment: No problem. @Jeff Schaller's answer is in did much simpler. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try issuing the following command

```
find /www \( -path "*/public/assets/images/*" -a  \( ! -path "*/public/assets/images/icons" -a ! -path "*/public/assets/images/icons/*" \) \) -o \( -path "*/.git*" \) -o \( -path "*/vendor*" \) -o \( -path "*/node_modules*" \) -prune -o \( ! -name ".env" \) -exec zip www.zip {} +
```

Explanation

The first expression that starts after `/www` and ends with with the `-prune` parameter states that the directories `.git`, `vendor`, `node_modules` and `public/assets/images` except for `public/assets/images/icons` are to be ignored by `find`.

`! -name ".env"` tells find to ignore files named `.env`

`-exec zip www.zip {} +` runs the `zip` command on the selected files, but the command line is built by  appending  each selected  file  name  at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files. The result is stored in file `www.zip`.

Comment: I don't see how this will work because it will include all of the directories alongside the `public/assets/images/icons` directory. It doesn't mention anything about `icons`. Also, what does the `@` do?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. Will fix my answer. The `@` states the end of exclude supplied  arguments.

Comment: This is the latest I have (not working but close I think): `find ./public/assets/images -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./public/assets/images/.*' | grep -oP '\./public/assets/images/(?!icons).*' | zip -rq application.zip . -x vendor/\* node_modules/\* .git/\* .env -@`

Comment: If we can find a way to insert the result from `grep` into the arguments of `zip` then I think we have it. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: In my opinion it is not necessary to use `grep` to solve this problem.

Comment: You may be correct, I don't really know what I am doing, I am kinda building this as I go based on what I am reading on the web. If you have a way to do with without then I am all ears :-D

Comment: I have posted up a new question that I think more clearly outlines what I need. I will keep this one open in case you are still working on an answer but will close if I get an answer to the other. See the other here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562775/dynamically-build-argument-for-zip-command

Comment: Your requirement can be fulfilled combining the usage of `find` + `zip`. I'm working on a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perfect, I shall look forward to see what you come up with. Thank you very much for your help thus far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103463/discussion-between-paulo-tome-and-ben-carey).

Comment: I will be performing this from the root of www directory, does that mean I change `/www` to `.`?

Comment: @BenCarey   Yes, replace `/www` by `.`

Comment: Just tested this and it works!!! Brilliant, thank you so much! Before I accept this as the answer, would you mind lending some assistance in also adding the following rule to the command: exclude all subdirectories of `infrastructure/Resources/assets/images` apart from `{icons,emails,brands}`? Does that make sense?

Comment: What does it mean `apart from {icons,emails,brands}`?

Comment: As in I want to exclude all subdirectories of `infrastructure/Resources/assets/images` apart from the following sub directories `icons`, `brand`, and `emails`

Comment: To exclude all subdirectories of `infrastructure/Resources/assets/images` its a matter of adding `-o \( -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images*" \)` to the list of directories to prune.

Comment: The problem is, I want it to exclude all of them apart from those I mentioned i.e. `icons`, `brand`, and `emails`

Comment: I get it. You also want to exclude al subdirectories of `infrastructure/Resources/assets/images` with the exception of `icons`, `brand` and `emails`.

Comment: Exactly! I have managed to get it working but the command is very long and I assume there is a way to shorten it. I added the following: `-o \( -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/*" -a  \( ! -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/brand" -a ! -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/brand/*" -a ! -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/emails" -a ! -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/emails/*" -a ! -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/icons" -a ! -path "*/infrastructure/Resources/assets/images/icons/*" \) \)`

Comment: Your solution is correct. There isn't any way of shortening it.

Comment: Okay perfect, thank you so much!!! :-D

Comment: You're welcome. ;)

Comment: Now it's the moment of truth to see if it works on my Bitbucket Pipelines. That's where the command is being executed. My app was too large to upload to an EB instance on AWS so I have had to strip out all media that is not used by the server and is hosted on the CDN, hence this command...